# Can a cookie be set when using jsonify?

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask

```
@user.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def check_oauthuser():
    token = request.args.get('token','')
    open_u_id = request.args.get('openUId','')
    _self_expires = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 3

    #re = Response()
    #re.set_cookie('name','1111111')

    if token!='' and open_u_id!='':
        set_user_login_cache(user_id, token)
        return jsonify(state=0,msg='success')
```

I want to set a cookie into the response header, but I use `jsonify` instead of creating a `Response`.  What can I do to add a cookie when returning `jsonify`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`jsonify` returns a `Response` object, so capture it before returning from your view and add the cookie then with `Response.set_cookie`.

```
out = jsonify(state=0, msg='success')
out.set_cookie('my_key', 'my_value')
return out
```

You might want to just add the value to the session cookie.  Flask's `session` will json encode values and sign  the cookie for security, something you have to manually do when using `set_cookie`.

```
from flask import session

session['my_key'] = 'my_value'
```